# Meteor miniMongo queries for date objects not working

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have lots of documents in miniMongo with `dateCreated` values between the dates outlined below. The values are stored like `dateCreated: ISODate("2014-05-10T16:00:00Z")`

But the query isn't able to pull up any of them (returns empty array);

```
startDate = new Date( "Thu Jan 01 2014 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (HKT)" );

endDate = new Date( "Thu Jan 01 2015 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (HKT)" );

Tests.find({ dateCreated: {$gt: startDate, $lt: endDate} }).fetch();
```

I also try to create the query programmatically but it still doesn't work.

```
dateCreatedRange = {$gt: startDate, $lt: endDate}

Tests.find({ dateCreated: dateCreatedRange }).fetch();
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Use momentjs for formating the date. here's what i did with my date range in my application

```
var date1 = moment(xdate1).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ");
var date2 = moment(xdate2).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ");
```

where xdate1 and xdate2 is coming from a date picker formatted as 'yyyy-mm-dd'

```
date1 = new Date(date1);
date2 = new Date(date2);
```

Then use this to query

```
Tests.find({ dateCreated: {$gt: date1, $lt: date2} }).fetch();
```

Comment: Do the dates that are in the documents in the collection have to be in momentjs formatting as well? Right now they are in ISODate format.

Comment: No, i saved my as myfieldname: new Date()... what i showed you is how you will be able to find and fetch the date from the collection.